# v-shown fail to read value from array index

Tags: vue.js

I have a table with rows. Rows are inside `tbody`'s that are clickable. I wanna show an extra row in form of a list under the clicked row with more information.

If the row or the 'list-row' is clicked again, the 'list-row' is hidden again.

My implementation is to create the 'list-row' under the original row and hide it. If the tbody(inside a tbody two rows, the original row and the corresponding 'list-row) is pressed, the extra row is toggled.

Right now, all of them are hidden/shown is pressed since i just have one Boolean variable that controll pressed/not pressed. I was thinking to use a `vector` instead.
This can be done by making  `clickStatus` to a array and replace `v-show="clickStatus"` with `v-show="clickStatus[indexa]"` instead.

This does not work! Nothing happends when a `tbody` is clicked. I know with help of logs that the array is changed but the show-function does not react. Any idea why it does not work and how to fix it?

```
<template id = "transactionTable">
<div> 
    <table class= "list-table">
        <thead>
            <th v-for="(index, labels) in inlabels" track-by="$index"> 
                 {{labels}}
            </th>     
        </thead>
        <tbody v-for="(indexa, s) in insubset" track-by="$index" @click="rowClicked($event)"> {{s}}
                <tr class = "subList" id = {{indexa}}   >
                    <td v-for="(indexb, e) in s") track-by="$index"  > {{ e }} </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr class = "mainList" v-show="clickStatus" > 
                    <td colspan = "8"  >
                        <div v-for="(indedc, column) in inlist[indexa]" track-by="$index"> {{label}}
                            <span> {{ column['name'] }} : {{ column['value'] }} </span> <br>
                        </div>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</template>


export default { //broadcast
    template: "#transactionTable",



    data : function() {
       return {
            clickStatus : false
        }
    },

    props : {

        inlabels: {
              default: function () {
                return { null }
              }
            }, 

        insubset: {
              default: function () {
                return { null }
              }
            }, 
        inlist: {
              default: function () {
                return { null }
              }
            }, 
    },

    methods :{
        rowClicked:function(e) 
        {
            this.clickStatus = !this.clickStatus;
            console.log(this.clickStatus);
        },

    },
}
```

First Edit

```
method{
            rowClicked:function(e, index) 
            {
                this.clickStatus[index] = !this.clickStatus[index];
                console.log(this.clickStatus);
            },
    }
    ready: {
        this.clickStatus = Array[100];
        for( int i = 0; i < this.clickStatus.length; ++i )
           this.clickStatus[i] = false;
}

v-show="clickStatus[indexa]"
```

Comment: change `v-show="clickStatus"` to `v-show="clickStatus[indexa]"`

Comment: Right now you are generating a `tbody` for every item in `insubset`. I hope that's what you want. Seems odd to me as a table has on `thead` and one `tbody`.

Use ids for your generated html elements, that's what you should do anyway. With Id's you don't need to safe an array or what every, because you can identify every single row or tbody. You know in which `tbody` you've clicked and can refer to the right element you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the index to your `rowClicked` function and use it to store the `clickStatus` at that index.

You should also declare `clickStatus` as an array instead of a boolean.

Comment: See my edit. As as explain in the text, I already tryied that but it does not catch the update when I press the button. I know the correct index value changes since i log the array but v-show does not catch it.